# Orbeon: reset value of hidden field

Tags: forms, orbeon, hiddenfield

I have an autocomplete field and radio buttons which have a visibility condition, is there any possible way to reset their value when the visibility condition is false оr to somehow get information about the visibility of those fields (something similar to /text() or /@label)?

Comment: It seems to me that [RFE 3152](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3152) covers what you are asking for. Is this correct? Also, for our information, what is the use case for wanting the value to be reset when the field becomes non-visible?

Comment: I see that it has been added for Orbeon Forms 2017.1, but I'm using 4.8. 
I have a radio buttons A and B, when A is 'yes', B is visible, if I select something for B and change my answer for A to 'no', B isn't visible but the value is persisted. Same goes for autocomplete (radio button A and autocomplete B).
I would like to somehow reset the value through calculated value (using the same expression as for visibility). Is there some way that could be done?
Or was I mistaken when I said that the xf:submission nonrelevant isn't available in this Orbeon version?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've tried dispatching an event, but since the fields aren't visible, it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Got it about this being on 4.8. Would upgrading to a newer version be an option at all for you? Is this for a form you wrote "by hand" in XForms, or are you using Form Builder?

Comment: Currently we aren't able to update, but I hope that in the near future we will.
I'm using FormBuilder.

Comment: Are you using your own `xf:submission` that you added to the source of the form, or using a service defined with Form Builder? If the former, then I would expect a `relevant="true"` to remove the non-relevant nodes. Have you tried this? Note you can't use [`nonrelevant`](https://www.w3.org/community/xformsusers/wiki/XForms_2.0#The_submission_Element), as it is only supported in more recent versions of Orbeon Forms.

Comment: Hi @avernet, sorry for the really late reply. I have not had time to work on this issue up until now, but since I can't use nonrelevant and I don't have information if the field was relevant or not when submitting the form content in this version, I have currently found a custom way to achieve this by adding a "non-relevant" node in the XForm and actions on xforms-enabled and xforms-disabled to all fields which remove or add the control name from the text node of "non-relevant" and after submitting, I remove the values of all controls which added to the "non-relevant" node.

Comment: I'm glad you found a way to make it work with 4.8. Are you still planning to update to a more recent version? (This way you'll benefit from new features, and support will also be easier.)

Comment: I hope we will update to the 2017.1 version this year (actually next year). Thanks!

Comment: OK, great! (Or, by then 2017.2, if everything goes according to plan.)